# WSO2 Admin services for .NET web application

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a JAVA web application which consumes WSO2 admin service - ServerAdmin and this need to be migrated to  ASP .NET technology.

I tried to get client stub for AuthenticationAdmin (to get cookie which is needed for subsequent Admin service requests) using the client method login (username,password,server-name) , and the method returns "true"
But , how can I get the cookie from the response ?Or any AuthenticationAdmin client method which returns cookie ?

[image]

Raw XML response as below :
[image]

XML Response message as below :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:loginResponse xmlns:ns="http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"><ns:return>true</ns:return></ns:loginResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: In the Raw response of the AuthenticationAdmin service, you will find the Cookie Header with JSESSION.

Comment: @Athiththan ,Thank you for the reply.                                                                            
 I tried to access the login(username,password,servername) method (from SOAPUI),
but couldn't find any value in Response header.
There is another method loginWIthRemeberMeOptions(username,password,servername)which returns  response as below but couldn't find any session values in response header
 <ax292:authenticated>true</ax292:authenticated>
 <ax292:maxAge>604800</ax292:maxAge>
 <ax292:value>wso2_dataservice-3c2b64c1-8c24-4363-8991-683861dgf1c2</ax292:value>

Comment: Can you share which WSO2 product you are using and the version? And I believe that you are receiving true as the response payload. Can you share the screenshot or the Raw request and response of the SOAPUI (mask the username and password)?

Comment: I have added the screen shot of SOAP request .We are using WSO2EnterpriseIntegrator - 6.5.0 version .Yes I am getting true value as response .

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of the Raw tab (not the XML tab) of both Request and Response?

Comment: I was missing port number 9443 in the endpoint URL .Got session ID back from response.Thanks @Athiththan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cookie is presented in the Response Headers. So, you will find the `JSESSION` Cookie in the Response Headers of the Authentication Admin service call. You can use `JSESSION` cookie to call the subsequent Admin Services in the WSO2 platform.